# The variable declared but value is never used error

Tags: asp.net

I searched in SO and found some similar questions, but they did not solve my problem.

I am using `ASP.Net` and here is my code :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
     int _new = 0;
     // other lines of codes which does not include _new

     for (int i = 0; i < _Array.Length; i++)
         {
            if (_Array[i] == "N" || _Array[i] == "NEW")
            {
                _new = 1;
            }
     }

     // other lines of codes which does not include _new
}
 }
```

I get the `The variable declared but value is never used error` warning on

```
 int _new = 0;
```

why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not done any process on the variable _new, you are only assigning the value to it

Comment: wow, that was quick and I missed that, thanks for noticing. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @ashik yeah don't declare it if you are not gonna use it.